# Yii routing on form action

Tags: php, forms, yii, routes

I have a problem where, when submitting my form, it seems to ignore my routing and redirects me to the Home instead.

In my main.php routing:

```
'<language\w+>/profile/<slug:[\w\-]+>'  => 'profile/index',
'<language\w+>/<action:\w+>'            => 'site/index',
```

My form:

```
<form action="<?php echo Yii::app()->getBaseUrl()."/".Yii::app()->language;?>
/profile/calendar" method="post">
```

Which outputs to

```
<form action="/domainname/nl/profile/calendar" method="post">
```

Note: domainname is there because I'm testing this on localhost.

However, when pressing the submit button it forwards me to the home instead of  the correct page. Simply visiting `/domainname/nl/profile/calendar` in the browser **does** work and gives me the correct controller. I don't know why it isn't working in the form.

In a different form on the same website, I have the following, which again *does* work fine for the routing:

```
<form action="/domainname/nl/profile/info" method="post">
```

The difference between these 2 forms is that the last one is created through CActiveForm widget and the first one isn't.

Comment: If you can open same url in browser then i dont thing there is something wrong in routing, just check your code, you might have somewhere in beforeAction or anyother place to redirect in case of POST, or you may have some nested form on page by mistake ? or any JS that can change action on the fly ?

Comment: @RasikhMashhadi none of those things. I think the problem is caused by the fact that I'm not using the same CActiveForm widget as in my other forms, though I can't put my finger on what exactly the issue is.

Comment: I never had such an issue ever, i have used forms with and without CActiveForm million times. You need to debug each and every step. Check if the control reaches your actionInfo() by echo something and die in first line.

Comment: @RasikhMashhadi it doesn't, it doesn't even reach my actionIndex() of ProfileController. It goes straight to the actionIndex of SiteController (which redirects to Home)

Comment: throw an exception in site index, and it will show to all calls stack, may be that will help you understand.

Comment: @RasikhMashhadi I'm not that experienced within Yii so I'm not sure what this means, but these are the first 2 lines (shown at bottom) `CWebApplication->processRequest()` , `CWebApplication->runController("site/index")` so it looks like the request itself directs to the wrong place.

Comment: I've managed to work around it by using CActiveForm after all. I think the `yii_cs_csrf_token` that is passed on from this form was required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to work around the issue by switching my manual form to use the `CActiveForm` widget after all. It seems I needed the `yii_cs_csrf_token` that is automatically generated by `CActiveForm`.

Answer (score 0):

Make simple post request to "/domainname/nl/profile/info" and watch for response headers. Or you can analyze existing requests with tcpdump or something simular

Comment: Problem was already "solved" as you can see in the comments. I'll post it as an answer myself so I can close the question.